# Line numbering problem with the AIP template

Tags: revtex, line-numbering

I am writing a paper based on the [AIP template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-submission-to-aip-journals/wdmsvzfjgvyj), and I want to add the line number. I tried with `lineno`, but it has some problems: as a standard (you can see that by opening the template in Overleaf), using `lineno` adds the line number on the left side of each line, but for the lines in the right columns the numbers overlap with the text of the left column, making it sometimes difficult to read them. I tried to add `switch` and `columnwise` to `\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}`, but it doesn't work (the position depends on the page, but it always causes ovelraps). Do you know how to solve this? An alternative way to do it would be to reduce the distance between line and line number, how do I do that?

Comment: Hi, would it be a solution to use per-page numbering with `\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}`? Also the spacing is controlled by `\linenumbersep` so something like `\setlength{\linenumbersep}{4pt}` could do the trick of bringing the numbers close enough.

Comment: Unfortunately `pagewise` does not work, it could be in conflict with other settings... However, `\setlength{\linenumbersep}{4pt}` does work, I solved it with that, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can influence the distance between the text and the line number by `\linenumbersep`. So placing the following line after you load `lineno` would help:

```
\setlength{\linenumbersep}{4pt}
```

This should allow the line numbers to fit in the intercolumn space.